# What does a “Cannot find symbol” compilation error mean here?

Tags: java, compilation

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a=sc.nextInt();
        int b=sc.nextInt();
        int n=sc.nextInt();
  for ( n=1 ; n<11; n++){
        int z = a + b(Math.pow(2,n+1) - 1) ;
      System.out.println(z);
     }
   } 
 }
```

and the error says like this 
Compile time error
Compile Message
Solution.java:18: error: cannot find symbol

```
int z = a + (b) (Math.pow(2,n+1) - 1) ;
                    ^
  symbol:   class b
  location: class Solution
1 error
```

Comment: Java doesn't work with operation like this 2(3-1), it needs 2*(3-1). In your case b*(Math.pow(2,n+1) -1)

Comment: Hi , thanks @ganchito55. I got it now !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to multiply the `int b` with `(Math.pow(2, n+1) - 1)`? If so, then you are missing a `*` to signify a multiplication sign likely causing the error. You can read more about the error on this post:

[Post on 'Cannot Find Symbol'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)